# ¿Por que no funciona :active de CSS en algunos navegadores móviles de un teléfono en particular?

Tags: html, css, diseño

Excelente tarde a todos, comenzaré explicando un poco la situación, actualmente estoy desarrollando el sitio web [Casayaa!](https://casayaa.com), en el cual existe un buscador (actualmente solo es el diseño) que está compuesto por algunas etiquetas de marcado `HTML` y estilizado con `CSS`, les dejo el código del buscador por aquí.

```css
.casayaa-search-box-container{
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 flex-direction: row;
 align-items: flex-start;

 width: 50%;
 height: auto;
 text-align: left;

 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);

 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.casayaa-search-box-container .casayaa-search-box-input{
 width: calc(100% - 50px);
 height: 50px;
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
 border: none;
 outline: none;

 text-indent: 10px;

 font-family: Verdana;
 font-size: 1em;

 background: transparent;

 /* Safari */
 -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.casayaa-search-box-container .casayaa-search-box-input::placeholder{
 color: #fff;
 opacity: 1;
}

.casayaa-search-box-container .casayaa-search-box-button{
 width: 50px;
 height: 52px;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 border: none;
 background: url(https://casayaa.com/img/busqueda.svg);
 background-size: 50% 50%;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 outline: none;
}
.casayaa-search-box-container .casayaa-search-box-button:active{
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}
.casayaa-search-box-container .casayaa-search-box-input:focus{
 background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section class="casayaa-search-box-container">
    <input class="casayaa-search-box-input" placeholder="Casa en la ciudad de..." type="text" name="">
    <button class="casayaa-search-box-button"></button>
</section>
```

Haciendo `click` sobre el botón con el icono de la lupa, el color de fondo de este cambia `(rgba(0, 0, 0, .1))` para acentuar un poco, esto funciona bien en la mayoría de los navegadores web de diferentes dispositivos móviles y de escritorio en los que he tenido la oportunidad de probar, sin embargo tengo un teléfono marca Lenovo modelo K6 con sistema operativo Android versión 7.0.0, en este dispositivo no funciona correctamente `:active`, al hacer `click` o mas bien tocar el botón, el color de fondo no cambia, en su lugar cambia la imagen de fondo, toma el logotipo del sitio (la imagen de la casa con una persona durmiendo), no logro comprender el porque, he revisado mi hoja de estilos completa y desde mi punto de vista no tengo algo que pudiera estar interfiriendo.

Esto me ha pasado usando los navegadores:

- Chrome 70.0.3538.110
- Opera 48.2.2331.133274
- Edge 42.0.0.2801

Les dejo una captura de pantalla del teléfono Lenovo K6.

[image: Captura de pantalla del teléfono Lenovo K6 - Chrome]

[image: Captura de pantalla del teléfono Lenovo K6 - Opera]

[image: Captura de pantalla del teléfono Lenovo K6 - Edge]

¿Sabe alguien por que pasa esto?

Comment: El error se ve muy extraño, pero haz una prueba.... en la definición del estilo del botón, en lugar de usar `background` y asignar el svg, usa `background-image`, por supuesto agrega `background-color: transparent` y algo como `transition: background-color 0.2s ease` para que no sea tan brusco el cambio... no tengo idea del porqué del error, pero se me ocurre que pruebes eso a ver si cambia el comportamiento.

Comment: Haré eso para verificar si ocurre algún cambio, gracias.